# EXCEL Auto Incrementing Alphanumeric Cell By 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently stuck with an alphanumeric cell problem in Excel.

Currently, i'm using this formula in a cell: **LookupList!$F$3**
***=$F$2&TEXT(RIGHT(InvoiceLists!A:A,5)+1,"00000")***

Which gives me a result of CSD00003, since in InvoiceLists!A:A I have row number 1 and 2.

> INVOICE NO.
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> CSD0003

The problem is when CSD00003 is inputted in row 3, it won't detect and generate CSD00004 in the 4th row and still showing CSD00003 (because it won't detect and increment alphanumeric cell, only detect normal numeric cell).

I've tried use ***=$F$2&TEXT(RIGHT(COUNTA(InvoiceLists!A:A),5),"00000")*** method, but when a previous row been delete, next generated number will be conflict.

So my problem is how to make LookupList!$F$3 detect and generate with alphanumeric instead of just number.

Thanks.

Comment: If you click into the formula cell and hit enter, does it render the correct result?

Comment: Also, is your autocalculate on, or is it set to manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I assume you want to generate an alphanumeric string with the numeric part = total no. of invoice + 1

If so, then use the followings:

`=$F$2 & TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(MAX((InvoiceLists!A:A<>"")*ROW(InvoiceLists!A:A)))+1,"00000")`

Comment: Thanks, with this formula it still only detect numeric number cell, still won't detect alphanumeric string cell.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Use CountA() instead of Count() please.

Comment: Thanks, this method works but there's is a problem when a previous row been delete, Invoice number will go back which duplicate.

Comment: ok. The revised formula can cater for blank cells in between.  From the application point of view, I wonder if you really want to remove an invoice number once it has been created, or you just need to mark it as deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult problem to handle in Excel or in a database.  I can offer a workaround, namely to just maintain a counter and the alpha components separately.  Then concatnate them together to generate the full ID.

```
   A   | B | C
1  CSD | 1 | CSD00001
2  CSD | 2 | CSD00002
e  CSD | 3 | CSD00003
```

Enter the following formula into `C1`:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, TEXT(B1, "00000"))
```